# Create an inserted_at datetime where filter using simple date string

Tags: date, elixir, where-clause, ecto

I'm trying to get records inserted after a certain date given to me by the client.

`2018-06-06`

Here's how I'm writing the query:

```
{:ok, date} = NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601(date_string)

from(
  m in query,
  where: m.inserted_at > ^date
)
```

> - (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :invalid_format}

And when I try to use a simple Date object:

> ** (Ecto.Query.CastError) lib/messages/search.ex:77: value `~D[2018-06-06]` in `where` cannot be cast to type :naive_datetime in query

How can I find all messages inserted after that dummy string date the client is passing me?

Comment: You get the match error because you are not giving right data to `from_iso8601/1`. Try appending some dummy time info and make query like: `NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601("2015-01-23 23:50:07")`

Answer (score 0):

You have an ISO 8601 date there, not a datetime. You can convert it into a `NaiveDateTime` (with hour, minute, second all set to 0) like this:

```
iex(1)> date_string = "2018-06-06"
"2018-06-06"
iex(2)> ndt = NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601!(date_string <> " 00:00:00")
~N[2018-06-06 00:00:00]
```

Now you can use `ndt` in your query and it will work.